# $T:P_n\longrightarrow P_n : Tp(t)=\frac{d}{dt}p(t)\text{ Find the norm of the operator}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $$P_n:=\bigg\{p:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R :deg(p)\le n\bigg\}$$
And define the norm $$\lVert p(t)\rVert=\max_{0\le k\le n}\lvert a_k\rvert \text{  where $p(t)=a_nt^n+...+a_1t+a_0$}$$

---

We define a linear operator: $$T:P_n\longrightarrow P_n :$$
$$Tp(t)=\frac{d}{dt}p(t)$$
Find the **||T||** norm.

---

Ok so my thoughts so far are:
$$p'(t)=\color{black}{\underbrace{na_n}_{b_n}}t^{n-1}\color{black}{\underbrace{(n-1)a_{n-1}}_{b_{n-1}}}t^{n-2}+...+\color{black}{\underbrace{1\cdot a_1}_{b_1}}+\color{black}{\underbrace{0\cdot a_0}_{b_0}}$$
$$\text{Hence}:b_k=k\cdot a_k,k=0,1,2,...,n$$
$$\text{So: } \lVert Tp(t)\rVert=\lVert p'(t)\rVert=\max_{0\le k\le n}\lvert b_k\rvert=\max_{0\le k\le n}\lvert ka_k\rvert\le n\max_{0\le k\le n}\lvert a_k\rvert$$
$$=n\lVert p\rVert $$
$$\text{Thus, }\quad \bbox[3px,border:2px solid red] {\lVert Tp\rVert \le n\lVert p\rVert  } \qquad (1)$$
$$\text{Let }p_0(t)=1\cdot t^n\Rightarrow\lVert p_0\rVert =1$$
$$\text{By the definition of the norm we get :}$$
$$\lVert T\rVert =\sup_{\lVert p\rVert=1}\lVert Tp\rVert\ge \lVert Tp_0\rVert=\lVert p_0'\rVert=\lVert n\cdot t^{n-1}\rVert=n\quad (2)$$
$$\text{Hence : by (1),(2) it implies that : }\lVert T\rVert=n. $$

---

Thoughts on that?
Thank you.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct.
The important arguments are mentioned, too.
For inequality (1) you could mention that it holds for all $p\in P_n$, which would improve the style slightly.